# How can I retrieve current Azure AD User informations (email, firstname, lastname) in web-forms hosted on Azure Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a web site solution (.net framework/web forms) hosted on azure web app.

I would like to retrieve (in Session_Start of Global.Asax) the current azure AD user informations but it doesn't work with this code :

```
    if (((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity) != null)
        string IdentityName = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Name;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name) != null)
        string name = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier") != null)
        string ObjectId = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName) != null)
        string GivenName = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Surname) != null)
        string Surname = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn) != null)
        string UPN = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;

    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email) != null)
        string Email = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use Graph Api to retrieve the users details by id like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

- You can use an middleware to get the currently logged on user informations, claims and add it to your Identity User.

```
 public class Middleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public Middleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
       {
            if (httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"))
            {
                 // Read headers from Azure and get jwt claims
                 var idHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"][0];
                 var idTokenHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN"][0];

                 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                 var jwtToken = handler.ReadToken(idTokenHeader) as JwtSecurityToken;
                 var jwtClaims = jwtToken.Claims.ToList();
                 jwtClaims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier", idHeader));

                 // Set user in current context as claims principal
                 var identity = new GenericIdentity(idHeader);
                 identity.AddClaims(jwtClaims);

                 // Set current thread user to identity
                 httpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
            }
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
       }


// Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class Middleware
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<Middleware>();
        }
    }
```

```
//and is startup use it like this: 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseMiddleware();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Global.asax Session_Start is called when a session is started, which is, say, when a browser hits your site. The browser user has not generally logged on at that point, so there's not going to be any `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` for you to grab. You should get an empty string.

If you add user info in the claims during authentication, you can get it with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I add user info in the claims, it's the first time I deploy on azure so I'm not expert...

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://joonasw.net/view/adding-custom-claims-aspnet-core-2) to add custom claims .